# Get a table style in Word VSTO

Tags: ms-word, styles, vsto

I can set a style for a table in Word VSTO with:

```
Me.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Style = "Table Grid 8"
```

How can I get the selected table style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.Net you need:

```
Dim style as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style    
style = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Style
```

The only difference with C# is the square bracket

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I can get the style this way

```
Globals.ThisDocument.Tables[1].get_Style();
```

Comment: hi. I've written my program in vba language and then turned it into VB.
Vba language program was working well, but in the language of vb does not work properly and could not get a table style.
I work in the VB language and this method is not in it.
Thanks